# PHP PDO Prepared statement with REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Prepared Statements… Bind variable as numeric range in REGEXP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548926/php-prepared-statements-bind-variable-as-numeric-range-in-regexp)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `file` REGEXP 'This string :var'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':var', 'exists');
$stmt->execute();
```

This throws error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

When I echo $query before the execute, I get:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `file` REGEXP 'This string :var'
```

How the hell do you bind variables in a regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: You need to tell mysql what column you wish to apply `REGEXP` to and a placeholders can only be used where a value can appear (thanks to @Barmar). For example, if you wish to search `col1` for `'This string :var'` you need to do

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE col1 REGEXP CONCAT('This string ', :var)
```

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't solve the problem. You can't put PDO placeholders inside strings. See the answer in the question I linked to above.