# PHP Prepared Statements... Bind variable as numeric range in REGEXP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, pdo

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `file` REGEXP '[:val-9]'";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':val', '1'); //I have also tried 1 without quotes
$stmt->execute();
```

Throws this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1139 Got error 'invalid character
>   range' from regexp

Is it possible to do this..

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `file` REGEXP '^[:val-9]'";` 

did you tried this one.

Comment: @Rafee Yeah mate just tried it. Same error message. I've also tried breaking out of single quotes `REGEXP '[':val'-9]'` and still get errors.

Comment: Have you tried binding the regex instead? `$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE file REGEXP :regex";` and then `$stmt->bindValue(':regex', '[' . '1' . '-9]');`?

Comment: @JoãoSilva Post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Placeholders can only be used where a value can appear, not embedded in strings. Try:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `file` REGEXP CONCAT('[', :val, '-9]')";
```